# Intelligent Unmasking of Commas in amount fields in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an amount edit text and its input type is Numeric.

As I type a number in an amount field, I use AfterTextChanged method in Text Watcher to parse as well as apply the currency mask '###,###,###' to insert commas in the keyed in number so that the displayed amount field is easily readable.

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###");
String formattedString = formatter.format(number);
editText.setText(formattedString);
```

However, while entering the value 14580000 to the editText,  I am getting this error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "14,580,000"
             at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
             at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
             at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
             at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
```

The error is a result of parsing (Integer.parseInt) the Edit Text field that has got commas. So is there an intelligent manner by which Android can recognise the edit text value as a masked value and hence automatically unmask i.e.strip off the commas in between.

Or, is this something I should not even attempt doing for the edit text with "numeric" input type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When parsing the String to an Integer use

```
String.replaceAll(String, String)
```

like this:

```
Integer.parseInt(formattedString.replaceAll(",",""));
```

This removes(replaces with an empty string) all the commas and the String should be parsed sucessfully.

Comment: I did try "replace" method before. Did not realize that there was replaceAll method. Thanks. Giving you up vote. Still, looking out for elegant solution that interprets this mask and does the needful